Tikz. How do I insert a label in front of an arrow?
I am not able to insert a text node - a label - in front of the point of an arrow: 
\begin{figure}[h]   
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \draw [->, red,  thick] (0,0) to [out=90, in=75] (10,10)
    node[pos=0.5, below]{9/10};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textbf{U}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}  


Just remove  node option pos=0.5 and it will work as you desired ...

If you did want a node at the halfway point, you would need to put it before the (10,10). I'm not sure why it ends up at the beginning - maybe @Zarko knows?

@cfr Nodes(/pics/coordinates) can only be placed implicitly on a to segment because it will be executed inside a group, all the to paths timer information are lost after it and the last one will be used (which is none here and it falls back to the origin).

@Zarko Thanks, it works. How is it? I miss the logic.

@cfr, \draw [->, red,  thick] (0,0) to [out=90, in=75] node[pos=1, below]{9/10} (10,10); works fine too.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Ah. Thanks. I didn't know or had forgotten the default is the origin, but, of course, that makes sense for to since nothing changes. [Actually, I'm not sure I mean this.]

@mario pos=0.5 requests the node be placed midway along the path. So, if pos did work here, your node would be half way along, rather than at the end where you want it. Removing pos puts the node at the current point more-or-less.
